# Alternative proof(s) for the fact that "Covergent sequences are bounded"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have not come across any alternative proof for the fact that "Convergent sequences are bounded".

The only proof that I have come across has the following idea - the sequence is divided into two parts i.e. a finite and infinite part. Due to convergence criteria the infinite part is bounded and every finite sequence is also bounded. Thus the sequence as a whole is bounded.

I am looking for alternative proofs with the hope that I may be able to look at the situation from different perspective? Please also mention if you have more than one alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think about it.  Let $S=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}\subset\mathbb{R}$.  Then a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ in a topological space $X$ converges to a point $x\in X$ iff the map $f:S\to X$ given by $f(1/n)=x_n$ and $f(0)=x$ is continuous.  Since $S$ is compact, this means that if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then $f(S)=\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}\cup \{x\}$ must be compact.  If $X$ is a metric space, this implies in particular that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is bounded.

(This proof isn't actually different from yours, it's just dressed up in fancier language.  If you chase through what's really going on in this proof, you're just saying that some ball around $x$ must contain all but finitely many $x_n$, so then finitely many balls contain every $x_n$.  I doubt that there's any truly different proof.)